# Excel VBA database access through ODBC not ADODB

Tags: sql, excel, vba, odbc

I am working on an Excel file that connects to a SQL database to update parameters on a piece of production machinery based on an analysis of part quality data. The file has been working in production for some time but a recent hacking attack on my company has caused us to review the security of all of our systems.

The old file version used ADODB with a hard-coded user name a password with narrowly defined database permissions. This meant any quality or engineering employee could run the Excel utility without being explicitly given server/database access. With our new security review, I wanted to switch the file to use windows authentication but I ran into some issues. It seems that using windows authentication through ADODB requires not just a database user, the automation team has permissions to create, but also a server login mapped to the database user which only an IT admin can create. I also worry that adding a large number of server-level users is not a wonderful idea.

The actual piece of production equipment uses a system-level ODBC connection with window authentication. This connection works fine with a database user without a server login. Because ODBC doesn't seem to need a server login it would make the management of the Excel file users much simpler and would allow the team in charge of the equipment and its database to handle it without IT.

Unfortunately, I have been unable to figure out how to execute queries and get results in VBA with an ODBC connection. I have tried Workbook.Connections("ODBCName").CommandText with an ODBC connection stored in the workbook but I don't see a way to directly get the result. The only option I can see is to map the query to cells in a hidden table and read them in VBA but this seems hackish. Also, I'm not sure how this would work for the results of queries other than SELECT like INSERT or UPDATE.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. An example of my old code is here, there are more routines that make similar queries:

```
    
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    cn.Open strCon
    
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Table.dbo.PART_INSPECTION_LOG WHERE PART_NUM = 'PartNo' AND DATA_TIME = " & dataTime
    rs.Open strSQL, cn

    If (rs.BOF And rs.EOF) = True Then
        linear_err = (Sheets("Adjustment").Range("E24").Value)
        rotational_err = (Sheets("Adjustment").Range("N24").Value)
        
        strSQL = "INSERT INTO Table.dbo.PART_INSPECTION_LOG (PART_NUM, TOOL_ID, USER_NAME, DATA_TIME, LINEAR_ERROR, ROTATIONAL_ERROR) VALUES ('PartNum', 'ToolNum', "
        strSQL = strSQL & "'" & Application.UserName & "', "
        strSQL = strSQL & dataTime & ", "
        strSQL = strSQL & linear_err & ", "
        strSQL = strSQL & rotational_err & ")"
    
        cn.Execute strSQL
    End If
    
    cn.Close
```